# How to insert updated and before updated data to a table with JSON in SQLAlchemy,Python?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to display the difference between original data and revised data, after trying many ways, we decide to insert updated and before updated data to a table called `history_table` with JSON.

How to insert changed dict and before updated dict to below table?

```
# table of `history_table`
before_updated                    updated             updated_time
  json of before_updated       json of updated           datetime
```

Below code will update 15 rows from different tables(sample code only has one table), so many tables need to be changed and saved, I am stuck in this for many days, thanks so much for any advice.

```
 class GetTestDetail(Resource):
    args = self.test.parse_args()
    print(args)
    id = args.get("id")
    def get(self):
        # get something
        data = db.session.query(Test.name, Test.days).filter(Test.id == id).first()
        return dict(data=data)

    def put(self):
        # change something
        args = self.test.parse_args()
        test = args.get("test")
        dict_test = db.session.query(Test).filter_by(id=id).first()
        test["name"] = 'Alice'
        test["days"] = 12
        {setattr(dict_test, k, v) for k, v in test.items()}
        db.session.commit()

        return {"status": True, "message": "Successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        return {"status": False, "message": "Failed"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your problem is with the code. First thing is to understand the logic or pick an approach and then you can write your code.

1. A simple way to do this would be to have two tables - one for 'new data' (your history table) and another table for 'current data'.
2. Each row in 'new data' would have columns for 'change number', 'creation datetime' and a column (foreign key) that links to the primary key in 'current data'. If you want to use one table to handle history for multiple tables, then you can also have a column to indicate which table this record is for. Example if you have different tables for customers, orders, order details, then those values will appear in the column (say we call it primary_table_name)
3. 

a) A brand new record will first go into the 'current data' table. After that, you create an entry in the 'new data' table with a change number of 0 and it references the primary key in the 'current data' table. Whenever you see a change number of 0, you know it is referring to the first entry(record) for that object.

b) Subsequent changes will first go into 'new data' and you increment the change number count. Note that this will be a different row (you don't overwrite the previous record). Then after saving to 'new data', you copy over it over to 'current data' and overwrite the row there.

In essence, your 'current data' table will always have the most recent record and is where you pull data to display to users. If users then want to see a history for a specific record, you just go to the history table and pull all rows for that record where change number > 1. You can have separate code to compute the diff between the records